# PHP - sending one email works but sending 2 emails won't

Tags: php, email

Consider this code:

```
<?php
//Original code: http://myprogrammingblog.com/2013/08/27/how-to-make-a-contact-form-     with-bootstrap-3-jqueryphphtml5jqbootstrapvalidation/
//Modified to send email confirmation to bidder and to write file with data

// check if fields passed are empty
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['firstName'])   ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message'])     ||
   empty($_POST['date'])        ||
   empty($_POST['itemNo'])      ||
   empty($_POST['itemName'])    ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
echo "No arguments Provided!";file_put_contents('results.txt', "No arguments Provided!", FILE_APPEND);
return false;
   }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$itemNo = $_POST['itemNo'];
$itemName = $_POST['itemName'];

// Require to process DB access and updates
require_once ('insertBid.php');

// create email notice and send it to administrator
$to = '******@gmail.com'; //admin email
$email_subject = "Nouvelle enchère de l'encan silencieux Équipe 300PAS";
$email_body = "Tu as reçu une nouvelle enchère.\n\n".
              "Voici les details :\n".
              "Nom: $firstName $name \n".
              "Date de la nouvelle enchère : $date \n".
              "Description de l'enchère : $itemNo - $itemName \n".
              "Courriel : $email_address\n".
              "Téléphone : $phone\n".
              "Montant soumis : $message $";
$headers = "From: ******@yveschaput.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

// create email confirmation and send it to bidder  
$to = $email_address; // bidder's email
$email_subject = "Confirmation de votre enchère";
$email_body = "Bonjour $firstName $name, \n\n".
              "Merci pour votre offre. \n".
              "Voici les details:\n \nVotre offre est pour : $itemNo - $itemName \n".
              "Date de votre offre : $date \n".
              "Montant de votre offre : $message $".
              "\n\nSi vous êtes le plus haut soumissionaire, vous serez averti par courriel ou téléphone ($phone) à la fin de l'enchère.".
              "\n\nL'équipe 300PAS Trophé Rose des Andes.";
$headers = "From: ******@yveschaput.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ******@yveschaput.com";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

Now, I have another similar script from my contact form that is sending one email to the administrator and it is working perfectly.
The only real difference the script I have posted here is the `require_once` to insert the data into the DB and the second email to the user.
The script works at least up to the call to the insertBid.php script since de DB do get updated. But no emails are being sent. I know it is not a server problem since the other script sending an email do work.

In my previous tests, before doing any backend scripting, this script worked but it didn't have that call to this insertBid.php.

Here is that insertBid.php script, if it helps you guys decipher this problem:

```
<?php
# connect to the database  
require_once('connect.php');

#On concatene le prénom et le nom dans une même variable
$fullName = $firstName . " " . $name;

#pour debug, on s'assure que les détails sont correct et on met le tout dans un fichier
$bid = $fullName. "," . $email_address . "," . $phone . "," . $message . "," . $date . "," . $itemNo . "," .  $itemName;
file_put_contents('results.txt', $bid, FILE_APPEND);

#Requête d'insertion de chaque offre dans la BD
$sql = "INSERT INTO encan(nom,email,phone,itemNo,itemDesc,bid,bidDate) VALUES (:nom,:email,:phone,:itemNo,:itemDesc,:bid,:bidDate)";
$q = $dbh->prepare($sql);   
$q->execute(array(':nom' => $fullName, ':email' => $email_address, ':phone' => $phone, ':itemNo' => $itemNo, ':itemDesc' => $itemName, ':bid' => $message, ':bidDate' => $date));
$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
return true;
?>
```

Any help is much appreciates. Thanks.

Comment: post any relevant error logs that you see in log file

Comment: what the the return true doing in insertBid.php

Comment: Side note: Installing [Test Mail Server Tool](http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/) can speed up email debugging, as it shows the email the instant local server sends it. Thus, no need to wait for it in receiving inbox.

Comment: Side note 2: As it currently stands, your script is open to spam abuse (recipient and content can be set by a spambot) and you're not doing proper encoding of non-ASCII characters. Consider using captchas and a mail library like [phpmailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) instead of the mail() function

Comment: The return true in insertBid.php was put there as I thought it was missing. Obviously, it is not needed. As for the error logs, I'm on a shared hosting services and I can't find any logs with some useful info in it. I don't think I have access to any meaningful logs.

Answer (score 0):

DAMN! I found an error_log file in my PHP folder, where all my PHP scripts are. It turns out it was a simple misnaming variable error that was stopping the script before completion.

In my insertBid.php script, I copy/pasted part of the code from another script and I forgot to change `$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();`. The PDO object is named $q, not $stmt.
I wasn't even using that line. Sheesh!

Now I'm using it to validate the SQL query, `if ($affected_rows !=0){return $affected_rows;}`,
and write a log file, from the calling script, so I can track what is going on more easily.

A total noob error, which is what I am.
Sorry to have taken some of your valuable time guys. (leaving room with the tail between my legs in shame)